# Changing the Hannover theme to fold subsections

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'm creating big presentation in `beamer` and I'm using `Hannover` theme to show sections, subsections and subsubsections.

The presentation is big so the size of the list in the navigation bar exceeds the height of the page.

Is there any way to don't show subsections and subsubsection that are in other sections than current section?

EDIT:

I want to get rid of the Yellow part of the image

[image]

EDIT 2:
Assuming the structure of the presentation is:

```
-SECTION 1
--SUBSECTION 11
---SUBSUBSECTION 111
---SUBSUBSECTION 112
--SUBSECTION 12
---SUBSUBSECTION 121
---SUBSUBSECTION 122
--SUBSECTION 13
-SECTION 2
--SUBSECTION 21
---SUBSUBSECTION 211
-SECTION 3
```

Also assuming that I'm on the page named SUBSUBSECTION 111, the navigation bar should show:

```
-SECTION 1
--SUBSECTION 11
---SUBSUBSECTION 111   <-- here I am
---SUBSUBSECTION 112
--SUBSECTION 12
--SUBSECTION 13
-SECTION 2
-SECTION 3
```

Comment: You say  so "the size of this list", which list are you referring to? Is is a ToC? The headline? The navigation bar at the sidebar? Can you add a little MWE showing your relevant settings?

Comment: I mean the navigation bar on each slide on left

Answer (score 4):

### Update

After the edit to the question, no predefined option is given to obtain the desired result, but you can use

```
\makeatletter
\beamer@nav@subsectionstyle{show/hide/hide}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\makeatletter
\beamer@nav@subsectionstyle{show/hide/hide}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one one one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection one two}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one two one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two one one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two two}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two two one}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### First version

Simply use the `hideothersubsections` for the theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}

\begin{document}

\section{A first test section}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}

\section{A second test section}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
\begin{frame} test frame in section~\thesection\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the sidebar for a frame on the first section:

[image]

An image of the sidebar for a frame on the second section:

[image]

Comment: That is almost what I want. However I still see sub-sub-sections of other sub-section in the same section.

Can I get rid of this also?

(Look into the edited post for visual explanation)

Comment: @Dzior Please see my updated answer, just under the "Update" title. Is it something like that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Still not exactly what I wanted :)
See my EDIT2 of original post

Comment: @Dzior Ah, I think I finally understand :) However, I don't think this kind of style is easy to define (subsubsections in beamer are not well supported, since they are preferably not used). If I can think of a solution I'll let you know.

Comment: That's actually the big problem with LaTeX :P the simplest things are so complicated :/